# Default value behaves differently when used in Function and when used with Cases

Tags: functions, pattern-matching

Consider this example:

```
 Cases[{4, x, 5 a , 6 x}, x_.*a_ :> x]

(*{1, 1, 5, 6}*)
```

It is clear that the `_.` took 1 as a Default value.

Now:

`f[x_.] := {x}` dose not work and `_.` Default value has to be user defined first

```
Default[f] = 0;
f[x_.] := {x}
f[]
(*{0}*)
```

It is little confusing that `_.` takes default value in some operation and has to be user defined with default value in other operation.

Any explanations?

Thanks

Comment: The functions `Times`, `Plus`, `Power` have built-in default values (1, 0, and 1, respectively).

Comment: Use `DefaultValues[Times]`, `DefaultValues[Plus]` etc. to see this. Now try `DefaultValues[f]` before you have attached any default values to it, and you will see that `f` has no built-in default values.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. It is clear now:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple and you were very close to seeing this yourself:

```
Default[Times]

(* Out[9]= 1 *)
```

As you see, the `DefaultValues` for `Times` and `Plus` are already built in.

Comment: I was very close yes but I would never seeing it myself before your answer. Thanks :)